# AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command'

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, discord.py

I have added this code:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def name(ctx):
username = ctx.message.author.display_name
```

On to the end of my line of code, and I get this error when trying to get the bot online:

```
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`discord.ext.commands.Bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot) instead of `discord.Client`.  `Bot` is a subclass of `Client`, so you can also use all of the `Client` functionality with a `Bot` instance

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

bot = Bot("!")

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Command executed")

await bot.run("TOKEN")
```

Comment: I'm now getting another error. ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Bot'```

Comment: Sounds like you tried just `import Bot` and not the full `from discord.ext.commands import Bot`

Answer (score 0):

```
client = discord.Client(intents=intents )
```

Check this :)

```
client=commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")
```

**This resolves my isssue :)**